# What is a Cyber Security Mesh?

Tags: mesh-network, security

What is cybersecurity mesh? I have been hearing from Gartner reports about mesh for cybersecurity ([example](https://www.gartner.com/smarterwithgartner/gartner-top-strategic-technology-trends-for-2021/)). But there is no substantial resource to explain what it is.

Answer (score 1):

That’s because they just made it up. The more we talk about it, the more we ask questions about it the more that executives use the terminology the more Gardener’s looks like they are trend setting

Comment: that may be true

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the made up terminology answer...

But I also do think the concept is something that might have a little merit. Think in terms of "Host Based" and "Network Based" security, those are very "device" focused. Is there a compromise on the device and in the network or not?

Yet with the push to more behavioral models, we include a large swath of information into the fold. "Insider threats" wouldn't be detected in the older Host/Network based models without adding aspects like UEBA.

If we add into the mix the various open information from social media, cloud sources and attribution requirements, we're really involving tools from everywhere outside of "traditional cybersecurity". When we go even more decentralized, trust and security is down to every transaction, not a device or network.

How do we control / manage all of that from a cybersecurity tool standpoint? Will that change the landscape / mentality significantly in the future? Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Cybersecurity Mesh by designing and implementing an IT security infrastructure that is not focused on building a single ‘perimeter’ around all devices or nodes of an IT network, but instead you create a smaller individual perimeter around each access point. This is a horizontal approach to a network rather than a traditional top-bottom approach. In the mesh, the access points can be managed from a centralized point of authority. This Cybersecurity Mesh can establish a more robust and flexible approach to a network’s security. When each node has its own perimeter the IT network manager can maintain and track different levels of access to various parts of a given network.